# Get values inside specific interval

Tags: mysql, sql

The client side sends an interval [6, 11] and I need to extract the 6th, 7th, ... 10th and 11th value from the resulted values after i perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` ORDER BY id DESC
```

The client can also ask for [12, 17], [18, 23] etc

I'm new at SQL, can anyone help? The web wasn't of much help to me.

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `long_description` text NOT NULL,
  `thumb` text NOT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Could you please show some contents of `projects` table?

Comment: [6,11] these are the ids ? or stored in other column ? please provide the table definition

Comment: No. first I need to sort them in descending order, and then from he list of resulting items I need to extract the 6th, 7th .... 11th item.  It's not dependent on the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `projects` 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT $offset,$amount
```

So for [6,11]

```
SELECT * 
FROM `projects` 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 6,6
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks :) I didn't know that LIMIT accepted 2 values. Thanks a lot !